# Running DESeq2 from rpy2

Tags: python, rpy2

I am trying to run DESeq2 through rpy2 for the first time and am having some difficulties.

```py
class py_DESeq2:
    
    def __init__(self, count_matrix):
        
        self.dds = None
        self.normalized_count_matrix = None
        self.vsd = None
        self.count_matrix = robjects.conversion.py2rpy(count_matrix)
        self.design_matrix = robjects.conversion.py2rpy(pd.DataFrame({'treatment':['ctrl' for i in range(count_matrix.shape[1])]}))
        self.design_formula = Formula('~ 1')
        
    def norm_counts(self, **kwargs):
        self.dds = deseq.DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData=self.count_matrix, colData=self.design_matrix, design=self.design_formula)
        self.vsd = deseq.varianceStabilizingTransformation(self.dds, blind=True)
        self.normed_count_matrix = deseq.assay(self.vsd)
        self.normed_count_matrix = to_dataframe(self.normed_count_matrix)
        self.normed_count_matrix = robjects.conversion.rpy2py(self.normed_count_matrix)
```

I get the following error at `self.normed_count_matrix = deseq.assay(self.vsd)`:

```py
module 'DESeq2' has no attribute 'assay'
```

The below code in R runs fine:

```
library(DESeq2)
countData <- read.delim("0.333404867983521.R.data.in.txt")
colData <- read.delim("0.333404867983521.R.groups.in.txt")

dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData, colData,design=~Treatment,tidy=TRUE)
norm <- varianceStabilizingTransformation(dds,blind=TRUE)
norm_matrix <- assay(norm)
norm_df <- data.frame(Gene=rownames(norm_matrix), norm_matrix)
write.table(norm_df, "0.333404867983521.R.data.out.txt", row.names = FALSE,sep="\t")
```

The norm object is a `<class 'rpy2.robjects.methods.RS4'>`.

There must be something I am missing here and a point in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open R and type:

```
library(DESeq2)
assay
```

you will see that the assay function is not actually coming from DESeq2, but from its dependency which is called `SummarizedExperiment`:

```
> assay
standardGeneric for "assay" defined from package "SummarizedExperiment"

function (x, i, withDimnames = TRUE, ...) 
standardGeneric("assay")
<bytecode: 0x5586a354db90>
<environment: 0x5586a3535e20>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x, i
Use  showMethods("assay")  for currently available ones.
```

you can confirm that `assay` is not part of `DESeq2` by using explicit namespaces in R:

```
> DESeq2::assay
Error: 'assay' is not an exported object from 'namespace:DESeq2'
```

and to confirm that it is indeed a part of `SummarizedExperiment`:

```
> SummarizedExperiment::assay
standardGeneric for "assay" defined from package "SummarizedExperiment"
```

Therefore in rpy2 you can use it like this:

```py
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

summarized_experiment = importr('SummarizedExperiment')
summarized_experiment.assay(self.vsd)
```

Comment: Much simpler than the object.do_slot() method I used :), thank you!